# MySQL I want to optimize this further

Tags: database, mysql, query-optimization

So I started off with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE hash IN (SELECT id FROM temptable);
```

It took forever, so I ran an explain:

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE hash IN (SELECT id FROM temptable);
+----+--------------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table           | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows       | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | TABLE1          | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2554388553 | Using where | 
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | temptable       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |       1506 | Using where | 
+----+--------------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

It wasn't using an index. So, my second pass:

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM TABLE1 JOIN temptable ON TABLE1.hash=temptable.hash;
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref                    | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | temptable       | ALL  | hash          | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                   | 1506 |             | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TABLE1          | ref  | hash          | hash     | 5       | testdb.temptable.hash  |  527 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+------------------------+------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can I do any other optimization?

Comment: Do you really need to `SELECT *`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can gain some more speed by using a [covering index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609343/what-are-covering-indexes-and-covered-queries-in-sql-server), at the cost of extra space consumption. A covering index is one which can satisfy all requested columns in a query without performing a further lookup into the clustered index.

First of all get rid of  the `SELECT *` and explicitly select the fields that you require. Then you can add all the fields in the `SELECT` clause to the right hand side of your composite index. For example, if your query will look like this:

```
SELECT  first_name, last_name, age 
FROM    table1 
JOIN    temptable ON table1.hash = temptable.hash;
```

Then you can have a covering index that looks like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_index ON table1 (hash, first_name, last_name, age);
```

Comment: I will remove the *. One quick question: If space is not really an issue, is it logical to add an index on all columns?

Comment: @Legend: Yes, in many situations it is recommended. In general the main disadvantage of a covering index over a regular one is that it takes up much more space, and that inserts and updates become a little bit slower (or take more resources). Unless you'll be inserting many new records per second, this is rarely an issue, and is often negligible.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that out and see if it works. My table has 2 billion records but I won't be updating them anymore.