# How SQL Server indexing can help using BETWEEN for given query

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, between

Does index helps in `BETWEEN` clause in SQL Server? 
If I have table with 20000 rows and query is:

```
select *
from employee
where empid between 10001 and 20000
```

Comment: Check the execution plan. (And, the answer is probably yes.)

Comment: Anything in where clause index will help.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. This is [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

It can do a range seek on an index with leading column `empid`. Navigating the B-tree to find the first row `>= 10001` and then reading all rows in key order until the end of the range is reached.

You might not get this plan unless the index is [covering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609343/what-are-covering-indexes-and-covered-queries-in-sql-server) though. Your query has `select *` so an index that only contains `empid` may potentially need to do 10,000 lookups to get the missing columns.

If `empid` is the primary key of `employee` then by default it will be the clustered index key (unless you specified otherwise) so this will automatically be covering and you should expect to see a clustered index seek.