# SQL gets slow on a simple query with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, mysql-slow-query-log

I have problem with MySQL `ORDER BY`, it slows down query and I really don't know why, my query was a little more complex so I simplified it to a light query with no joins, but it stills works really slow.

Query:

```
SELECT
    W.`oid`
FROM
    `z_web_dok` AS W
WHERE
    W.`sent_eRacun` = 1 AND W.`status` IN(8, 9) AND W.`Drzava` = 'BiH'
ORDER BY W.`oid` ASC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

The table has `946,566` rows, with memory taking `500 MB`, those fields I selecting are all indexed as follow:

```
oid - INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
status - INT INDEXED
sent_eRacun - TINYINT INDEXED
Drzava - VARCHAR(3) INDEXED
```

I am posting screenshoots of explain query first:
[image: image of explain query]

The next is the query executed to database:
[image: executed query to database]

And this is speed after I remove ORDER BY.
[image]

I have also tried sorting with DATETIME field which is also indexed, but I get same slow query as with ordering with primary key, this started from today, usually it was fast and light always.
What can cause something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kind of query you use here calls for a composite [covering index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609343/what-are-covering-indexes-and-covered-queries-in-sql-server).  This one should handle your query very well.

```sql
CREATE INDEX someName ON z_web_dok (Drzava, sent_eRacun, status, oid);
```

Why does this work?  You're looking for equality matches on the first three columns, and sorting on the fourth column.  The query planner will use this index to satisfy the entire query. It can random-access the index to find the first row matching your query, then scan through the index in order to get the rows it needs.

**Pro tip**: Indexes on single columns are generally harmful to performance unless they happen to match the requirements of particular queries in your application, or are used for primary or foreign keys.  You generally choose your indexes to match your most active, or your slowest, queries. **Edit** You asked whether it's better to create specific indexes for each query in your application. The answer is **yes.**

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i am going to try it this way. But with this thinking, it's better to create for every different search different group of indexes instead of single ones on same table?

Comment: I've created CREATE INDEX eracunindex ON z_web_dok (`Drzava`, `sent_eRacun`, `status`, `dat_zavrsena`) and query run in 0.0007 seconds, thank you, i was thinking about re-indexing my whole table..

Comment: **Boom! 3.3 seconds to 700 microseconds.** Please see my edit. And please take a look at https://use-the-index-luke.com/ to learn about effective indexing.

Comment: Adding to the final "Yes":  Once you have designed the best index for each SELECT, get rid of dups and overlapping indexes.  Specifically:  When you have `INDEX(a,b)`, you don't need `INDEX(a)`.  But `INDEX(b)` cannot be eliminated by it.

Comment: Among the [MySQL Utilities](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/utilities/) is a nice little command-line utility called [mysqlindexcheck](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-mysqlindexcheck/). It will scan your database's tables and suggest indexes to drop because they're redundant with others.

Comment: Be cautious -- If you have a monthly task that is the only user of a query, it may suggest that it be dropped.

Answer (score 1):

There may be an even faster way.  (Or it may not be any faster.)

The `IN(8, 9)` gets in the way of easily handling the `WHERE..ORDER BY..LIMIT` completely efficiently.  The possible solution is to treat that as `OR`, then convert to `UNION` and do some tricks with the `LIMIT`, especially if you might also be using `OFFSET`.

```
( SELECT ... WHERE .. = 8 AND ... ORDER BY oid LIMIT 10 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... WHERE .. = 9 AND ... ORDER BY oid LIMIT 10 )
ORDER BY oid LIMIT 10
```

This will allow the covering index described by OJones to be fully used in each of the subqueries.  Furthermore, each will provide up to 10 rows *without* any temp table or filesort.  Then the outer part will sort up to 20 rows and deliver the 'correct' 10.

For `OFFSET`, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#or