# Extremely large amount of time to perform a simple SQL query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

About `tableA`

- On MySQL 5.7.38 (AWS RDS)
- Contains +6.000.000 rows
- Property `last_activity_at` is set as an `INDEX` and has `datetime` format
- Property `project_uid` is set as an `INDEX` and is part of a Foreign Key

---

I'm performing the following SQL query

```
SELECT  project_uid, COUNT(uid) AS "count"
    FROM  tableA
    WHERE  last_activity_at >= "2023-05-01 00:00:00"
      AND  last_activity_at <= "2023-05-31 23:59:59"
    GROUP BY  project_uid
```

Here is the result (only performance)

```
117 rows in set (5 min 49,69 sec)
```

Here is the `EXPLAIN` results of the query above

```sql
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys                                                                                                               | key                            | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tableA | NULL       | index | IDX_2dd9918084b7ec339b29123b7e,IDX_acd46110be997a5678aa809f1c,FK_c0bc0d43ba64ca68b4fc7b7a095,IDX_8d2721775c4645ba9c620ec9fa | FK_c0bc0d43ba64ca68b4fc7b7a095 | 147     | NULL | 6235932 |    50.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

Here is the result without `group by` (which is still a lot for a simple where query)

```
1376493 rows in set (31,74 sec)
```

Here is the `EXPLAIN` of the query without `GROUP BY`

```
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+--------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys                  | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+--------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tableA | NULL       | ALL  | IDX_8d2721775c4645ba9c620ec9fa | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 6237888 |    50.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+--------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

---

I'm trying to understand two things here :

- Why adding a `group by` impact performances that much even with a `where` clause that is supposed to reduce the number of rows to group ?
- Why the query without the `group by` is still taking 30 sec on a 6M rows table ? Maybe it's just me but 6M is not that much for a database ?

Thanks for your help. If you have any optimization recommandation I'll be glad to read it!

Comment: Is the EXPLAIN the same with and without the GROUP BY?

Comment: @SimonGoater just edited with the explain, seems different.

Comment: Create composite index by `(last_activity_at, project_uid)`. Use DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY.

Comment: The thing is, i need to do a count ;-) edited the original query with the count

Comment: The proposed index should help with (i) where clause (ii) the data inside leaves (project_uid) could be used for grouping; MySQL won't have to touch the actual table  for the query.

Comment: I'm not in general a fan of creating indexes just to persuade the db engine to do a query a particular way. Maybe you can just try different variations of the query like for example SELECT a.project_uid, COUNT(a.project_uid) AS "count" FROM (SELECT project_uid FROM tableA WHERE last_activity_at BETWEEN "2023-05-01 00:00:00" AND "2023-05-31 23:59:59") a GROUP BY a.project_uid;

Comment: Yeah I tried that and still had same or even poorer results :-( It seems grouping on a 1M rows is not working very much. Also tried with by adding the composite index, without any results :-(

Comment: 5 mins to do a GROUP BY on 1.37m rows does sound suspiciously slow. Can you give mysql more memory?

Comment: It currently has 2GiB RAM, shouldn't it be enough ?

Comment: Hmm, I would have thought so. Sorry, out of ideas.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so that we can get a clue of what `FK_c0bc0d43ba64ca68b4fc7b7a095` is.

Comment: Did you mean `COUNT(uid)` or `COUNT(project_uid)` or `COUNT(*)` -- If both columns exist, it makes a big difference.  If the count'd column is never NULL, you are better off with `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Which Engine are you using?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much disk space does the table take?

Comment: "part of a Foreign Key" -- Which part?  If it is the "wrong" part, it is useless.  Again, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query contains correctly named columns, this index should help your query.

```
CREATE INDEX lastact_puid_uid 
      ON tableA (last_activity, project_uid, uid);
```

Why does this help? The first column of the index accelerates the date-range WHERE clause, and the other two [cover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609343/what-are-covering-indexes-and-covered-queries-in-sql-server) the query. That means the query can be satisfied directly by doing a [range scan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html) on the index.

Why doesn't it help much? Because COUNT() needs to look at every row in range. And there are many of them. Counterintuitively, COUNT() is a slow operation. That's because it promises a completely accurate result even on a busy table with other clients doing various transactions.

Comment: If we put `last_activity` first, then I'm afraid a filesort has to be done in order to group `project_uid` together. Depending on the actual number of rows matching the where condition, if the row count is huge but the number of distinct `project_uid` isn't high, could it be better if we put `project_uid` before `last_activity` ?

Comment: Please be aware that "filesort" is a misleading name. It doesn't actually use file-system files to sort unless the sort step involves so much data that it must spill from RAM. With a small `project_uid` cardinality the filesort won't be expensive. At any rate the only way to know which index works better is to try one, then the other.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. To be more precise, it should be "sort". And regarding indexing, low selectivity could take a toll on an obvious index choice, which might end up picking a seemingly suboptical one we originally ruled out.  Since the OP is using 5.7, it's more difficult to find the cost at each stage without `explain analyze`. But still, using slow log is neat to find the response time and rows examined. The way to reach optimum is to try. Thank you anyways.