# How does a non-clustered index require less logical reads than a query with a where clause on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, query-optimization, non-clustered-index

I'm taking a online tutorial/course on Performance tuning. I'm not understanding how a non-clustered index seems to be requiring significantly less logical reads than a query that just designated a where clause.

My understanding is a select query with a where clause will search through an entire specified column and only present the data that matches the requirements of the where clause.

The non-clustered index is created specifying the where clause in the exact same way, but when you run it it will only pull the exact data that was specified in the where clause, without doing a page-scan.

They seem to be functionally written the same, so how is the non-clustered index specifically pulling the data instead of searching the table? My best assumption is that a non-clustered index is running a select when it's generated, saving the data that matches the where clause, and automatically presenting it every time the non-clustered index is called. However it's most likely more technical than that, so if I could get some insight on this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: A *clustered* index is jargon for an index that contains all the data for the table. Typically it is an index on the table's primary key.  So other indexes aren't clustered.  All indexes contain copies of some table data, organized for rapid access. You may be asking about *covering* indexes. Read this for some good material. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609343/what-are-covering-indexes-and-covered-queries-in-sql-server

Comment: Think searching for "Jones" in the telephone book (this is equivalent on searching in NC index on column which it is indexed on). It's easy cause you can just skip to J directly. While for example searching for phone of someone living on "Easy Street" is not so fast in the phone book, because it's not organized by Street. Then you need to look through every page until you find what you're looking for (This is equivalent of clustered index scan).

Comment: @O.Jones A covered index as far as I know, is just a non-clustered index that specifies several columns to ensure that you don't need to reference the clustered index (further increasing the resource pull on a scan/seek). If I am understanding what you said however, "All indexes contain copies of some table data" that means my assumption was correct and that non-clustered indexes simply keep the data written to the drive so it can be automatically pulled instead of SQL Server doing a scan for the data.

Comment: Another upside is that NC index only contains the columns it's indexed on (simplified), which clustered index contains whole row data. So if you have to scan 100k rows of NC index, you are maybe reading through 10% of total data that exist in those rows.

Comment: Downside of NC: it only contains parts of data, for the rest you need to get it somewhere else (from Clustered index). So, if you doing a `SELECT *`, you usually need to do key lookups from the "big index". If you do too many lookups, SQL Server might decide to use a scan anyway, because it will be less expensive than doing lookup one by one

Comment: A clustered index and a non-clustered index are essentially the same, except that the CI contains *all* columns as `INCLUDE` (ie not part of the key). The NCI does less reads because you don't need to scan the whole thing (assuming it's keyed on the `WHERE` clause) whereas the CI would be keyed by something else, typically the Primary Key. Also even if you do have to scan it all, it's faster because there is less data to scan. This falls away if you then have to do Key Lookups back to the CI.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking about a filtered index. That only stores index rows matching the `WHERE` clause. And this is just implemented by adding appropriate filter to the execution plan for the `CREATE INDEX` and appropriate operators to plans that write to the table to ensure the index only stores rows matching the filter predicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My best assumption is that a non-clustered index is running a select when it's generated, saving the data that matches the where clause

In a sense, that is correct.  Whenever you add an non-clustered index to a table, the index stores a copy of the columns you specify as part of the index (or as an include).  That copy of the data is then sorted in the way specified by the index to make future look-ups of that data easier.

Essentially, indexes are trading space for time.  By using more storage space to store a sorted copy of data, you can search through that data much more efficiently.  The down side is that the server must now maintain multiple copies of the data, so updating a column not only modifies the underlying table but also any indexes referencing that column.  This is why you need to choose your indexes wisely and not just index everything.